# Do not run the command "runas"

Tags: postgresql, cmd, admin

I have a service does not start PostgreSQL. To view the error log, you can use the command (not to run out of the administrator):

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin>runas /user:postgres "C:\Program
>   Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\postgres -D "C:\Program
>   Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data""

However, after entering this command error appears:

```
    RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred | /netonly] ]
    /user:<username> <program>

    RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred] ]
    /smartcard [/user:<username>] <program>

    RUNAS /trustlevel:<trustlevel> <program>

    /noprofile <...>
    /profile <...>
<...>
```

Can you please tell how to write this command?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have extra spaces in your command at the end that may be messing things up and I believe you have to specify the hostname or domain where the user account exists. Try this:
 `runas /user:hostname\postgres "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\postgres -D C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data"`

Comment: Probably you mean "extra quotation marks". But the problem is the argument of the `-D` switch is a file path that has spaces. It is likely that it will not be interpreted correctly when RUNAS runs the command. So the quotes are kind of necessary there, only the question now is how to nest them in RUNAS.

Answer (score 0):

As follows from [this Super User thread](https://superuser.com/questions/182454/using-backslash-to-escape-characters-in-cmd-exe), nested quotes in RUNAS should be escaped with a backslash. So, your command should look like this:

```
runas /user:postgres "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\postgres -D \"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data\""
```

Comment: This prompts for the password of the "postgres" account. If it even has one I have no idea what it is.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Neither do I, I have to admit. At least it shows that `runas` found no issues with the command line supplied, and ran it, just what the OP was trying to achieve.